# what is a quick reacting text on mouse over function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried the following already:

```
html title="whatever" tag
onmouseover="javascript:alert('Whatever')
```

these both work fine, but i find the delay before the text box appears way to long for my purposes. what is one i can use the has a instant or close to instant reaction on the mouse over event?

```
<p><font color="black" title="大地(Daichi) ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land">(大地)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="が(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">(が)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="揺れ(Yure) vibration/flickering/jolting/tremor">(揺れ)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="始め(Hajime) beginning/start/outset/opening/  first / origin/  such as .../not to mention ...">(始め)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="、(、) Japanese comma">(、)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="警報(Keihou) alarm/warning">(警報)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="が(ga) indicates sentence subject / indicates possessive /  but/however/still/and">(が)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="鳴り(Nari) ringing/sound">(鳴り&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>)(<font color="black" title="響い(Hibii) no dictionary result, likely a conjigated verb">響い</font>)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="black" title="た(ta) indicate past completed or action/ indicates light imperative">(た)</p>
```

Yes i know the delay is short, but for my purpose i consider it too long. Also that the mouse must be still for it to show also makes the delay seem longer.  So basically i need an instant msg window, even if the mouse is in motion over the text.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to notice an `onmouseover` delay, it's pretty much instant. You're probably just doing it wrong. But no code, no help.

Comment: CSS `:hover` is better for some purposes, but @ahren +1.

Comment: see my update please -> ahren

Comment: Please don't use `font` elements. They're **old**, and very non-semantic. Also, there's no code in there that is triggering any event... that's just flat html.

Comment: i dont see how css hover can help me print message box, it works instantly but i can only see this changing the styling of the text. How can it be used for this purpose in my question?

Comment: the above code is using the title html tag, to make a message box on mouse over... it works, but its slow. in my opinion. thats why im asking for something else to use.

Comment: my apologies, i thought you were talking about the delay of the title tag, but now i see you were speaking of the onmouseover event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS tooltips. Basically what you're going to do is push the title bit off the screen then bring it back on hover. There is no delay and it can be styled very nicely.

There is a very good example of how to do this here: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

And an example using your first example here: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/PBsJA/

As per SO standards I'll post the code here, but I am not taking credit for writing it, just relating it.

HTML:

```
    <p><span class="tooltip">(大地)<span class="classic">大地(Daichi) 
    ground/earth/the solid earth/the  land"</span></span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
color: #000000; outline: none;
cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
margin-left: -999em;
position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
position: absolute;
left: 1em;
top: 2em;
z-index: 99;
margin-left: 0;
width: 250px;
}
.tooltip:hover img {
border: 0;
margin: -10px 0 0 -55px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
.tooltip:hover em {
font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}
.classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
.custom { padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em; }
* html a:hover { background: transparent; }​
```